# How to set cookie in browser using loopback?

Tags: node.js, cookies, loopbackjs

I am just starting off with loopback development and I just want to know how to set cookie in browser using loopback. One can send cookie in express framework of nodejs by setting it in headers and then access it later.

```
response.writeHead(200, {
    'Set-Cookie': 'mycookie=test',
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  });
```

So How to do this with loopback response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It had a simple solution. Using core node.js to solve it:

as we have context in loopback so:

```
context.res.setHeader("Set-Cookie",'cookie='+ cookieId);
```

This would do the trick in loopback as well.

Answer (score 2):

Loopback will work alongside Express, so you could use the [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) support and [cookie parser middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) from Express given you already know it.

Comment: Yeah actually not express but using core node.js would do the same.